# var_dump keeps saying false

Tags: php, steam, var-dump

My code trying to call to a steam api JSON file will not output to a var_dump
it just continues to say bool(false)

```
<?php
$steamkey = "removed";
$id_user = '76561198059606697';

$apifr = "http://a...content-available-to-author-only...d.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamkey."&steamids=".$id_user."";

print("(test) JSON File : $apifr"); 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$apifr);

$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I'm not sure how to use CURL and I don't know whats going wrong here.

Comment: ideone.com/TV0Y0L -- Code here showing bool error

Comment: That means the curl request is failing.

Comment: How do you expect it to work in ideone.com when you have a fake URL?

Comment: I'm not sure what about it is failing, I have something printing "apifr" when I had my key I could copy exactly from the console and the url would open the JSON

Comment: Use `echo curl_error($ch);` to see the reason why it's failing.

Comment: It prints "Could not resolve host: www.api.steampowered.com" What would I do to fix this if anything?

Comment: It should just be `api.steampowered.com`, not `www.api.steampowered.com`

Comment: I only added that to test it, It said the same with just http://

Comment: What error do you get when you use the correct hostname?

Comment: "Could not resolve host: api.steampowered.com"

Comment: Then there's a problem with the DNS on the machine you're running the script on, because that name resolves fine for me.

Comment: I just ran the same code on my other machine ( I could understand if this laptop is a bit weird) but I still got the same issue. Is it possible that its an ideone issue?

Even when ran on my host it says " couldn't connect to host "

Comment: I think ideone.com is blocking network access. I tried my company's URL and it also failed. But when I ran the same script on my local machine, it worked.

Comment: I also tried your original script on my machine and it worked.

Comment: They probably don't want people using their server to launch attacks on other sites, so they block DNS and cURL.

Comment: I ran it locally and the code you provided is absolutely fine and working.

Comment: I guess my host is blocking CURL as well. That might explain the majority of my errors today.

after looking into it, it seems thats the issue. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Shared hosts blocking external access is not unheard of; but often they will open it up for you if you ask (IME at least). So now that's sorted, I suggest you remove your steam key from the example.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an issue with my host. Thanks for all the help -resolved